# Exact number of subsets

Tags: python

I need to generate `n` subsets with `k` elements of a basic given set. I know how to generate *all* subsets, but how can I make just `d` subsets?

Here is my function for getting all subsets with `m` elements:

```
def find(S,m):
    return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))
```

Comment: Are there any additional requirements for which subsets you want to find?  Do you want just the first n subsets from all subsets based on some order, or do you want random subsets?.  Does the function need to be stable (it returns the same output each time it is given the same input ) within a particular run, a particular python version, all python versions, or is it allowed to be unstable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get them randomly, you can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random
def find(S, m, d):
    return random.sample(list(itertools.combinations(S, m)), d)
```

The above code will be very inefficient if you plan on calling the function regularly. For a fixed S and variable m, you can first build a dictionary:

```
S = "ABCDE"
fixed_dict = {m: list(itertools.combinations(S,m)) for m in range(len(S)+1)}
def find2(m, d):
    return random.sample(fixed_dict[m], d)
```

A more efficient one, that populates the dictionary when needed, for different S and m:

```
comb_dict = {}
def find3(S, m, d):
    try:
        return random.sample(comb_dict[(S,m)], d)
    except KeyError:
        comb_dict[(S, m)] = list(itertools.combinations(S, m))
        return random.sample(comb_dict[(S,m)], d)
```

For larger samples which are more irregular that hashing would not help much, you can also try:

```
def find4(S, m, d):
    combs = set()
    while len(combs) < d:
        combs.add(tuple(sorted(random.sample(S, m))))
    return combs
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you all for fast and useful answers.

Comment: Is there a way that I could add a probability to elements that can show up?For example to add that probability for n elements from basic array  to show in those subsets is equal for all

Comment: @Tim Do you want to assign probabilities to the set elements (for example A: 0.2, B: 0.7, C: 0.1) or to the possible subsets ((AB): 0.1, (AC): 0.2, ...)? With random.sample they are equally likely in both cases. For assigning different probabilities, you can use numpy's random.choice like this: `np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 2, replace= False, p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2])` This will return a random sample of 2 elements without replacement where C has the highest probability and A has the lowest.

Comment: I want same probabilities for set elements,according to your answer,I have what I need in function above?

Comment: Yes they are equally likely. Note that it generates all combinations and then selects from them. If you need to call the function regularly, this is inefficient if you have large sets. Based on the use case it is possible to modify the function to get a more efficient version.

Comment: Is there a way to generate only n subsets,not all of possible?

Comment: Yes, there are several alternatives. If the length of S is fixed, you can generate first and assign to a dictionary. If not, you can create a dictionary of C(S, m)s and fill when called, use the keys for subsequent calls. Or you can randomly select m elements d times (with a condition that prevents replacement). But like I said, it depends on the use case. If you further clarify what your aim is, a more efficient solution can be found.

Comment: According from above comments and code,I have a function that returns n random subsets of all subsets from basic set. It would be better done task if I could just generate and return n subsets,not just chose from all possible generated.

Comment: Function find4 is what I need! Thanks a lot @ayhan

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the requisite number of items from the generator of all combinations.

```
import itertools

def find(S, m, d):
    """Returns at most d subsets of S, each of size m."""
    return list(itertools.islice(itertools.combinations(S, m), d))

print find('ABCD', 2, 4)
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you can do this:

```
a = itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5],2)

count = 3

for x in a:
    if count > 0 :
        print x
        count = count - 1
```